# Is there any way to read batch of events from event hub in databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

My Requirement is i should read 1000 messages from event hub at a time in azure databricks and do some processing and then read the next 1000 messages in the queue.

On a whole i should continously read 1000 messages at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value of maxEventsPerTrigger to 1000.

**maxEventsPerTrigger** - Rate limit on maximum number of events processed per trigger interval. The specified total number of events will be proportionally split across partitions of different volume.

Sample Code -

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs.

val cs = "<your-connection-string>"
val eventHubsConf = EventHubsConf(cs)
  .setConsumerGroup("sample-cg")
  .setMaxEventsPerTrigger(10000)
```

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/streaming-event-hubs#eventhubsconf

Comment: I guess it will trigger even if the events received is less that 1000, but My system has to wait till it gets 1000 messages.